# blob texts after backup and restore

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, phpmyadmin, blob

Updated Question :

I had one old script with mysql 5.5.46 . i was storing my text in one columnt with blob type. my text was persian like this : سلام خوبی جه خبر  .
after some month's i changed blob column to longblob column with phpmyadmin with gui(without any converting query).
everything work's correctly but i get backup from my mysql and restored this db after 2 years. now it's not show my persian characters correctly.english text is ok but persian text's is going someting like the hex i mentioned in my question.
I need text's stored in `page_about` and `page_contact` columns in this table:
Creating Table :

```
    mysql_query("CREATE TABLE `".$prefix."ProFolio_info` (
                      `id` int(5) NOT NULL auto_increment,
                      `page_about` blob NOT NULL,
                      `page_contact` blob NOT NULL,
                      PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
                    ) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1") or die(mysql_error());
```

Updating Data :

```
$info_query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$prefix."ProFolio_info ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,10");

   while($info_row = mysql_fetch_array($info_query)){
        $about_page = html_entity_decode($info_row['page_about']);
        $contact_page = html_entity_decode($info_row['page_contact']);

    if(isset($_POST['change_settings']) && $LOGGEDIN == 'yes'){

    $new_aboutpage = clean_page($_POST['about_page']);
    $new_contactpage = clean_page($_POST['contact_page']);


    if($about_page != $new_aboutpage){
        mysql_query("UPDATE ".$prefix."ProFolio_info SET page_about = '$new_aboutpage' WHERE id = '$info_id'");
    }
    if($contact_page != $new_contactpage){
        mysql_query("UPDATE ".$prefix."ProFolio_info SET page_contact = '$new_contactpage' WHERE id = '$info_id'");
    }
```

get texts from DB :

```
 <textarea name="contact_page"><? echo str_replace('<br />', '', $contact_page); ?></textarea> 
 </div>
```

i tested some query like cast and convert and convert column to longtest but result is the same and i have wrong chracters.

I think it stored with latin1 collation but I select column with utf-8

**HEX**

```
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
```

i uploaded my script [in github](https://github.com/ascrypt/mytest)
also uploaded script in my server and sending text from script but data going to db correctly ! i think it's just because of my backup of database. 
you can check my ready script from [here](http://209.190.20.251/~afshin/) and view my text's from kave note's menu;

Comment: The scope of this question keeps changing on every edit and it's not clear what you're asking. Try breaking down the problem into small chunks, like restoring the old database

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 places to "say" utf8:

1. The data in the client must be utf8-encoded.  (It probably was.)
2. `SET NAMES utf8` or equivalent.  (You took care of that in `new PDO`.)
3. `CHARACTER SET utf8` on the table or column declaration.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE, but do not try to fix it if it says latin1.
4. On the html page, `<meta ... charset=UTF-8 ...>`

Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM tbl WHERE ...` so we can see whether the data was messed up in the table.  There two possible fixes for the data; we need to see the hex to know which fix to apply.

Comment: I Add New Details in my Question , Thanks

Comment: That hex represents `arefeh:23 esfande 90:manam injam ,sal..` and has htmlentities such as `&sect;` generating `§`.  But nothing that is non-ascii.  Hence, it is all valid utf8, too.  I need to see the hex for the line with ` سلام این ` or someting else that is going 'wrong'.

Comment: are you find the solution ?

Comment: That still smells like htmlentities in ascii.  So, I will assume that it was mangled (perhaps repeatedly) _before_ inserting.  Let's see the `INSERT` code (including the connection code).

Comment: please look at my source on github  [link]https://github.com/ascrypt/mytest
thanks

Comment: Based on the use of `html_entity_decode`, I have to assume you are not storing utf8, but instead have stored htmlentities.  This is a complication that I don't care to dig into.

Comment: Your question here mentions PDO, but the code you point to has the _deprecated_ mysql_* API; are we looking at the same code?

Comment: this is my old project , and now i just want to use from database of this. so i  use pdo in my new project to get data from this database,

Comment: Is there any way to fix characters problem ?

Comment: Maybe.  I don't yet understand (1) how the data was inserted, (2) what data was inserted, (3) how the data is being read, and (4) what it looks like after it has been read.  You have addressed all 4 of those, but the pieces don't fit together.  Please start over with a sample bit of text, together with the SQL and/or htmlentities() calls that affect the data.  Show it getting into the table, the hex in the table, and the steps coming out.  If possible, make a short program to reproduce the bad text.

Comment: I updated my question . please check it dear Rick . special thanks for your attention

Comment: Please switch from `mysql_*` to `mysqli_`; it handles character sets better.  Also, let's see the <form...> and <meta...> in the html.

Answer (score -1):

I have too got the same problem the main reason is windows uses different kind of character encoding for different characterset. I have found the package [convert character set](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1360-PHP-Conversion-between-many-character-set-encodings.html). It has solved my problem and it may solve your too.

Comment: That makes no sense. Character sets == encodings. I.e. iso-8895-1 on Windows is the same as on Linux.